# $a^Tx=b$ denotes a hyperplane. Is it always true that $a//x$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

$a^Tx=b$ denotes a hyperplane. Is it always true that  $a//x$? $x \in R^n$ $a\in R^n$ anb $b \in R$.From this data can we infer that $\vec a$ is parallel to $\vec x$ and if yes why?

Comment: what $a//x$ means? :)

Comment: $a$ parallel to $x$

Comment: I don't see any reasons for such a thing to hold at least from geometrical intuition for $n=3$! Why you think that it may hold?

Comment: The very question "is $a//x$?" seems weird to me. The hyperplane is the set of *all* $x$ such that the equation holds, isn't it? Most of them are not parallell to each other, how could they possibly all be parallell to $a$?

Comment: I am asking because I saw that if a line parallel to $a$ passes through the origin and intersects the hyperplane at point $x_1$ then $x_1=\frac{ba}{|a|^2}$ which can hold true only if $x_1$ and $a$ are parallel

Comment: There may exist such  $x$ but it is not true for **all** $x$ satisfying that equation. That's all.

Comment: Ok, about the case I wrote which is line parallel to $a$ pasees through the origin and intersects the hyperplane at $x_1$. Why in this case $a$ parallel to $x_1$?

Comment: I will write you an answer. :)

Comment: Take a look at the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reasons for ${\bf{a}}$ and ${\bf{x}}$ to be parallel for **all** ${\bf{x}}$ satisfying ${{\bf{a}}^T}{\bf{x}} = b$. However, suppose we want to find **one** ${\bf{x}}$ which satisfies ${{\bf{a}}^T}{\bf{x}} = b$ and is parallel to ${\bf{a}}$ which means ${\bf{x}} = \alpha {\bf{a}}$. So we have

$$\eqalign{
  & {\bf{x}} = \alpha {\bf{a}}  \cr 
  & {{\bf{a}}^T}{\bf{x}} = \alpha {{\bf{a}}^T}{\bf{a}} = \alpha {\left\| {\bf{a}} \right\|^2}  \cr 
  & \alpha  = {{{{\bf{a}}^T}{\bf{x}}} \over {{{\left\| {\bf{a}} \right\|}^2}}} = {b \over {{{\left\| {\bf{a}} \right\|}^2}}} \cr} \tag{1}$$

So if we choose $\alpha $ in the way above, ${\bf{x}}$ will satisfy the equation of the hyperplane and is also parallel to ${\bf{a}}$. Finally, the **special** ${\bf{x}}$ having this property is given by

$${\bf{x}} = {b \over {{{\left\| {\bf{a}} \right\|}^2}}}{\bf{a}}\tag{2}$$

Comment: Cool thanks! But I still don't understand the following: Suppose that a parallel to $a$ line passing through the origin intersects the hyperplane at $x_1$. Then $x_1$ is parallel to $a$. Why this specific x_1 is parallel to $a$?

Comment: I understand the math but I am having hard time visualizing this in $R^2$.
I mean if eq2 holds yes they are parallel. But I want to show that they are parallel in order to reach the eq2.

Comment: Let me clarify, if ${\bf{x}}$ is parallel to ${\bf{a}}$ and is on the hyperplane then it is given by $(2)$. If $(2)$ holds then ${\bf{x}}$ is parallel to ${\bf{a}}$ and lies on the hyperplane. So what is your problem now?

Comment: I completely understand what you wrote, thanks a lot, What I don't understand :why $x$ is parallel to $a$ when I draw a line through the origin parallel to $a$ intersecting the plane. It's more kind of geometrical question than algebraic!

Comment: Are you talking in $n=2$ for geometrical interpretation?

Comment: yes! for n = 2.

Comment: Can you specify your hyperplane in $n=2$? Does it pass through the origin? If you are assuming such a thing I might say in that case, $b = 0$ and hence ${\bf{x}} = {\bf{0}}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30398/discussion-between-dimitri-c-and-h-r).